# Adding Variable to URL In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to pass city name in URL. I have declared Variable city and I am passing it in URL but  it is not reading variable I have tried many methods but they are not working.

```
   const Weather=({city})=>{
  const [weather,setWeather]=useState('')
    useEffect(() => {
  
    axios
      .get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=58hgf1d8d36bf336f347d6cc9fbc7&query=${city}`)
      .then(response => {
        setWeather(response.data) 
      })
  }, []) 
// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be ` instead of ' as follows:

```
axios.get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=Your_access_Key&query=${city}`)
    .then(response => {
      setWeather(response.data) 
    })
```

Hope this resolves the issue while passing dynamic city to the URL. Also make sure that you are passing the right **access_key** too.

Comment: .get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=65f1d8d367f596bf336f347d6cfbc7&query=${city}`)
          .then(response => {
            setWeather(response.data) 
          })
      }, [])  It is also not working access key used is also correct.

Comment: I tried accessing the URL with Germany as the query param. It returns the error "invalid_access_key". Please have a look at it. Try generating a new access key & give it a try. That should resolve the issue.

Comment: Yeah, this works. here's the working URL for reference - http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=65f1d8d367f596bf336f347d6cc9fbc7&query=Texas

Comment: Check whether you are getting the value for "city" properly from the parent component. If that's correct, this code should work.

Comment: there was error i was passing it as a capital . Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 2):

You're using incorrect [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax. You need:

```
.get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=Your_access_Key&query=${city}`)
```

But it also looks like you're missing an access key in this request.